# How to get the post term name of a custom taxonomy in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I am trying to change *(add some)* in plugin file  [Retailcrm для wordpress/woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-retailcrm/), [Github](https://github.com/retailcrm/woocommerce-module) Especially the part that will allow me to **add the name of the custom taxonomy of the product** *(related to the manufacturer)* to xml.

The problem is that something is wrong with my code, **I can not get the name of the taxonomy.**

This is the original part of php file:

```
$product_data = array(
            'id' => $product->get_id(), 
            'productId' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_id() : $product->get_id(),
            'name' => $product->get_name(),
            'productName' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_title() : $product->get_title(),
            'price' => $this->get_price_with_tax($product),
            'purchasePrice'=> WC_COG_Product::get_cost($product),
            'picture' => $image[0],
            'url' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_permalink() : $product->get_permalink(),
            'quantity' => is_null($product->get_stock_quantity()) ? 0 : $product->get_stock_quantity(),
            'categoryId' => $term_list,
            'dimension' => $dimension,
            'weight' => $weight,
            'tax' => isset($tax) ? $tax['rate'] : 'none'
        );
```

I have a taxonomy pa_proizvoditel, this is an attribute of the product.

My guess is to do this:

```
$vendor = get_term( $product, 'pa_proizvoditel' );
        $product_data = array(
            'id' => $product->get_id(), 
            'productId' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_id() : $product->get_id(),
            'name' => $product->get_name(),
            'productName' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_title() : $product->get_title(),
            'price' => $this->get_price_with_tax($product),
            'purchasePrice'=> WC_COG_Product::get_cost($product),
            'vendor'=> $vendor->name,
            'picture' => $image[0],
            'url' => ($this->get_parent_product($product) > 0) ? $parent->get_permalink() : $product->get_permalink(),
            'quantity' => is_null($product->get_stock_quantity()) ? 0 : $product->get_stock_quantity(),
            'categoryId' => $term_list,
            'dimension' => $dimension,
            'weight' => $weight,
            'tax' => isset($tax) ? $tax['rate'] : 'none'
        );
```

That is to add:

```
$vendor = get_term( $product, 'pa_proizvoditel' );
```

and

```
'vendor'=> $vendor->name,
```

As the plugin developer suggested, but in this case in xml we will see the **product name** in **`<vendor>`**.

How to get the name of this taxonomy correctly?

Comment: Is it a product attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

**As it is product attribute** *(starting with "`pa_`")*, you can simply use in your code array the WC_Product method `get_attribute()`, that will give you the term name:

```
'vendor'=> $product->get_attribute( 'pa_proizvoditel' );
```

Comment: Hi! This will give me name of the taxonomy pa_proizvoditel in each <vendor> line in xml, but not each product vendor.

I mean each product has its own vendor
Product a <vendor>VENDOR_A</vendor>

Comment: @kh1 Sorry I understand now… I have updated my answer and it should give what you expect.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you so much! You are awesome as usual! Have a good day!